# Is there a symmetry argument that the running minimum of a Wiener process is the negative of the running maximum of that process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, maxima-minima

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Running_maximum) provides a derivation of the running maximum of a Wiener process, which turns out to be a half-normal distribution. The resulting expected value of the running maximum of the Wiener process is simply $\sqrt{\frac{2t}{\pi}}$ where $t$ is the time. Would the running minimum also have a half-normal distribution, resulting in an expected running minima of $-\sqrt{\frac{2t}{\pi}}$ via an argument of symmetry?

Comment: Yes. Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Wiener process. Then $(-X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is also a Wiener process

Comment: It is not that they are equal, but that they have the same distribution and so expectation